# In Perl, how can I get the fields in this CSV string into an array without spaces?

Tags: perl, arrays, csv, split, spaces

if I have a string, say:

```
my $string = "A, B,C, D , E ";
```

How can I put this into an array in Perl without the leading and trailing spaces? So what I want is only a single letter in each array element. What I currently do is this:

```
my @groups = split /,\s*/, $string;
```

But this is obviously not enough, as the trailing spaces are still there. Any help appreciated. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Then strip leading/trailing spaces before you split and match the leading/trailing spaces in the split expression.

```
my $string = " A, B,C, D , E ";
$string =~ s/^\s+//;
$string =~ s/\s+$//;
my @groups = split /\s*,\s*/, $string;
```

Using a module like [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV) is probably better than trying to do your own CSV parsing, though.

Comment: That faq talks about the trimming leading/trailing whitespace, so I'm not sure what you're wanting to draw attention to.

Comment: Unless your input is guaranteed to be this simple, the folks who've steered you towards Text::CSV are right: you don't want to parse it yourself.  If there are any commas embedded in the data, this simple split statement will break-up fields it shouldn't.

Comment: @jamessan I think there used to be a caution about `\s*` in that question or maybe I was thinking of something else. I just think your code is doing too much work.

Comment: @jamessan I guessed wrong. Your code is about 30% faster than the `split` and `map` strategy.

Answer (score 5):

```
my @groups = map { s!^\s+!!; s!\s+$!!; $_ } split /,/, $string;
```

or

```
my @groups = $string =~ /([A-Z])/g;
```

However, unless the input is really as simple as you have shown, you would be better off using [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::CSV) or [Text::xSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::xSV).

Comment: Why are you using ! as a q{} delimiter, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Paul Nathan: Because I get very annoyed that SO treats the trailing `//` in `s/\s+$//` as a comment character and grays out the rest of the line.

Comment: @Sinan: makes sense! It annoys me too.

Comment: @FM: That alternation is notoriously slow. Don't do it in one s///.

Comment: See my map comment on Paul Nathan's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
@groups = split /,/, $string;
#remove whitespace now.
@groups = map { s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; $_ } @groups;
```

Note: the regex can be simplified I'm pretty sure, just haven't worked it out yet.

Comment: You're all really amazing! This worked really good! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: s/// will transform the elements in @groups, therefore this is a useless use of map. You can just do: s/^\s+//, s/\s+$// for @groups;
Or use Filter in Algorithm::Loops.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to limit yourself to `split`, you just use a match with the `/g` modifier.

```
my $string = " A, B,C, D , E ";
my @groups = $string =~ /\s*([^,]+?)\s*,?/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure I'm not missing something, after trying to demystify your examples, I came up with this:

```
my $string = " A, B,C, D , E ";
$string =~ s/\s+//g;
my @groups = split /,/, $string;
```

Would work either I guess?

Comment: This removes ALL whitespace, not just whitespace around commas and at the beginning/end of line.  For example, if you have $string = " Bob Jones, George Jetson, Foo Bar" then your code strips the spaces between the words too.